# The touch event not working for button and textview in iOS Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uitextview

I have a button and a Textview which I'm adding dynamically on click of add button. But the new textview and button which I have added doesn't recognise my touch. I have created the event recognition everything but still the touch event is not handled.
[The touch in the textview which is marked in red is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwLwb.jpg)

Also the Add and Remove button is not working. I have created the touch event for that but the function itself is not getting called that means it is not taking the touch gesture. This is my code

```
- (void)RemoveChemical1Tapped:(UIButton *)sender {

    _ans6Constraint.constant = 340;
    [self reloadTable];

}



 - (void)viewDidLoad{
        @try{
        [super viewDidLoad];

        if(self.isReceived==true){
            [_HSSwitch setEnabled:NO];
        }

            [_addChemical addTarget:self action:@selector(addChemicalTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
             [_RemoveChemical1 addTarget:self action:@selector(RemoveChemical1Tapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

         // NSLayoutConstraint *top = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_ans6Text4 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:100];
        UILabel *titleLbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
        [titleLbl setText:@"Questionnaire"];
        [titleLbl setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [titleLbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Semibold" size:17.0]];
        [self.navigationItem setTitleView:titleLbl];

        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:63.0/255.0 green:29.0/255.0 blue:11.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
        UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)];
        [backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(back:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        UIBarButtonItem *backBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:backButton];
        [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:backBarButton];

        if (!self.isLiteNVD) {
            UIButton *saveButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)];
            [saveButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PropertyFence"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [saveButton addTarget:self action:@selector(save:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            UIBarButtonItem *saveBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:saveButton];
            [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:saveBarButton];
        }


        _datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
        [_datePicker setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [_datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
        [_datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

        _datePickerPast = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
        [_datePickerPast setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [_datePickerPast setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
        [_datePickerPast setMaximumDate:[NSDate date]];
        [_datePickerPast addTarget:self action:@selector(pastDateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

        UIView *paddingView1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
        [_ans3Text1 setClipsToBounds:NO];
        [_ans3Text1.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
        [_ans3Text1.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
        [_ans3Text1.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
        [_ans3Text1 setLeftView:paddingView1];
        [_ans3Text1 setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];

        UIView *paddingView13 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
        [_ans4Text1 setClipsToBounds:NO];
        [_ans4Text1.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
        [_ans4Text1.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
        [_ans4Text1.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
        [_ans4Text1 setLeftView:paddingView13];
        [_ans4Text1 setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];

        UIView *paddingView14 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
        [_ans4Text2 setClipsToBounds:NO];
        [_ans4Text2.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
        [_ans4Text2.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
        [_ans4Text2.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
        [_ans4Text2 setLeftView:paddingView14];
        [_ans4Text2 setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
        [_ans4Text2 setInputView:_datePickerPast];

        [_ans4ImageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
        [_ans4ImageView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
        [_ans4ImageView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
        [_ans4ImageView.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];

        [_ans4Button setClipsToBounds:NO];
        [_ans4Button.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
        [_ans4Button.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
        [_ans4Button.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];

        UIView *paddingView2 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
        [_ans5Text1 setClipsToBounds:NO];
        [_ans5Text1.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
        [_ans5Text1.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
        [_ans5Text1.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
        [_ans5Text1 setLeftView:paddingView2];
        [_ans5Text1 setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];

        UIView *paddingView3 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
        [_ans6Text1 setClipsToBounds:NO];
        [_ans6Text1.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
        [_ans6Text1.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
        [_ans6Text1.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
        [_ans6Text1 setLeftView:paddingView3];
        [_ans6Text1 setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
            UIView *paddingView3new1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
            [_Ans6Text1new1 setClipsToBounds:NO];
            [_Ans6Text1new1.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
            [_Ans6Text1new1.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
            [_Ans6Text1new1.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
            [_Ans6Text1new1 setLeftView:paddingView3new1];
            [_Ans6Text1new1 setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];

        UIView *paddingView4 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
        [_ans6Text2 setClipsToBounds:NO];
        [_ans6Text2.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
        [_ans6Text2.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
        [_ans6Text2.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
        [_ans6Text2 setLeftView:paddingView4];
        [_ans6Text2 setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
        [_ans6Text2 setInputView:_datePicker];
            UIView *paddingView4new1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
            [_Ans6Text2new1 setClipsToBounds:NO];
            [_Ans6Text2new1.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
            [_Ans6Text2new1.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
            [_Ans6Text2new1.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
            [_Ans6Text2new1 setLeftView:paddingView4new1];
            [_Ans6Text2new1 setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
            [_Ans6Text2new1 setInputView:_datePicker];

        UIView *paddingView5 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
        [_ans6Text3 setClipsToBounds:NO];
        [_ans6Text3.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
        [_ans6Text3.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
        [_ans6Text3.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
        [_ans6Text3 setLeftView:paddingView5];
        [_ans6Text3 setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
            UIView *paddingView5new1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
            [_Ans6Text3new1 setClipsToBounds:NO];
            [_Ans6Text3new1.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
            [_Ans6Text3new1.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
            [_Ans6Text3new1.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
            [_Ans6Text3new1 setLeftView:paddingView5new1];
            [_Ans6Text3new1 setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];

        UIView *paddingView6 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
        [_ans6Text4 setClipsToBounds:NO];
        [_ans6Text4.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
        [_ans6Text4.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
        [_ans6Text4.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
        [_ans6Text4 setLeftView:paddingView6];
        [_ans6Text4 setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
            UIView *paddingView6new1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
            [_Ans6Text4new1 setClipsToBounds:NO];
            [_Ans6Text4new1.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
            [_Ans6Text4new1.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
            [_Ans6Text4new1.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
            [_Ans6Text4new1 setLeftView:paddingView6new1];
            [_Ans6Text4new1 setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];

        UIView *paddingView7 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
        [_ans7Text5 setClipsToBounds:NO];
        [_ans7Text5.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
        [_ans7Text5.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
        [_ans7Text5.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
        [_ans7Text5 setLeftView:paddingView7];
        [_ans7Text5 setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
        [_ans7Text5 setInputView:_datePickerPast];

        UIView *paddingView8 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
        [_ans7Text1 setClipsToBounds:NO];
        [_ans7Text1.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
        [_ans7Text1.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
        [_ans7Text1.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
        [_ans7Text1 setLeftView:paddingView8];
        [_ans7Text1 setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];

        UIView *paddingView9 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
        [_ans7Text2 setClipsToBounds:NO];
        [_ans7Text2.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
        [_ans7Text2.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
        [_ans7Text2.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
        [_ans7Text2 setLeftView:paddingView9];
        [_ans7Text2 setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
        [_ans7Text2 setInputView:_datePickerPast];

        UIView *paddingView10 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
        [_ans7Text3 setClipsToBounds:NO];
        [_ans7Text3.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
        [_ans7Text3.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
        [_ans7Text3.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
        [_ans7Text3 setLeftView:paddingView10];
        [_ans7Text3 setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];

        UIView *paddingView11 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
        [_ans7Text4 setClipsToBounds:NO];
        [_ans7Text4.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
        [_ans7Text4.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
        [_ans7Text4.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
        [_ans7Text4 setLeftView:paddingView11];
        [_ans7Text4 setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
        [_ans7Text4 setInputView:_datePickerPast];

        UIView *paddingView12 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
        [_ans8Text1 setClipsToBounds:NO];
        [_ans8Text1.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
        [_ans8Text1.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
        [_ans8Text1.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
        [_ans8Text1 setLeftView:paddingView12];
        [_ans8Text1 setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
        [_ans8Text1 setInputView:_datePickerPast];



        [_ans9Text1.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
        [_ans9Text1.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
        [_ans9Text1.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
        [_lastAnswers.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
        [_ntButton.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
        [_resetAll.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
        [_msaBtn.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
        [_gapButton.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
        [_neButton.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];

        [_submitButton.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
        [_submitButton.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
        [_submitButton.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];

        [_HSBtn.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
        [_nfasBtn.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];


          //[self.tableView beginUpdates];
           // [self.view addConstraints:@[ top]];
    //        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_addChemical];
    //
    //        [self reloadTable];
    //        [self.tableView reloadData];
           // [self.tableView bringSubviewToFront: _addChemical];
    //        NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_questionArr.count-1 inSection:0]];
    //
    //        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arr withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            //[self.tableView endUpdates];

        NSDictionary *attrDict = @{
                                   NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:13.0],
                                   NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor yellowColor]
                                   };
        NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"I agree with declaration * "];
        [string addAttributes:attrDict range:NSMakeRange(0,25)];
        [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(25,1)];
        [string addAttribute:NSExpansionAttributeName value:@-1 range:NSMakeRange(25,1)];
        [_DeclarationLbl setAttributedText:string];
        [_consDeclarationBtn.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];

        [_signatureView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
        [_signatureView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
        [_signatureView.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];

        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100;

        NSDictionary *userDic = [[DBHelper getSharedInstance] getCurrentUser];

        if (self.operationType == OperationType_Quick){

            if ([self.answersDic objectForKey:@"ResponsibleContactSignature"]) {
                UIImage *consImage = [self.answersDic objectForKey:@"ResponsibleContactSignature"];
                self.signImg.image = consImage;
                [self.consDeclarationSwitch setOn:YES];
            }
            else if (![[userDic objectForKey:@"UserSignaturePath"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
                NSString *dbPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
                UIImage *consImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[dbPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[userDic objectForKey:@"UserSignaturePath"]]];
                self.signImg.image = consImage;
                [self.consDeclarationSwitch setOn:YES];
            }
            else{
                [self.signImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"signature"]];
            }
        }
        else if (self.operationType == OperationType_Edit){

            if (![[self.NVDDic objectForKey:@"ResponsibleContactSignature"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
                NSString *ENVDPath = [[DBHelper getSharedInstance] ENVDPath];
                UIImage *consImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[ENVDPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[self.NVDDic objectForKey:@"ResponsibleContactSignature"]]];
                self.signImg.image = consImage;
            }
            else{
                [self.signImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"signature"]];
            }
            if (![[self.NVDDic objectForKey:@"DeclarerAcknowledgement"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] && [[self.NVDDic objectForKey:@"DeclarerAcknowledgement"] boolValue]) {
                [self.consDeclarationSwitch setOn:YES];
            }
        }
        else if (![[userDic objectForKey:@"UserSignaturePath"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {

            NSString *dbPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
            UIImage *consImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[dbPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[userDic objectForKey:@"UserSignaturePath"]]];
            self.signImg.image = consImage;
            [self.consDeclarationSwitch setOn:YES];
        }
        else{
            [self.signImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"signature"]];
        }

        [self.nfasSwitch setEnabled:NO];
        [_nfasBtn setHidden:YES];


        if (![[self.NVDDic objectForKey:@"HasNFASQuestion"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] && [[self.NVDDic objectForKey:@"HasNFASQuestion"] boolValue]) {
            self.hasNFAS=TRUE;
           // [_nfasSwitch setOn:YES];
           //[_nfasBtn setHidden:NO];
            [_nfasSwitch setOn:YES];
            [_nfasBtn setHidden:YES];
        }
        else{
            [_nfasSwitch setOn:NO];
            [_nfasBtn setHidden:YES];
        }

        if (![[self.NVDDic objectForKey:@"HasHealthStatement"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] && [[self.NVDDic objectForKey:@"HasHealthStatement"] boolValue]) {
            if(self.isReceived==true){
                [_HSSwitch setOn:YES];
                [_HSBtn setHidden:YES];
               self.isReceivedHasHealthStatement=true;
             }else{
                 [_HSSwitch setOn:YES];
                 [_HSBtn setHidden:NO];
             }
        }
        else{
            [_HSSwitch setOn:NO];
            [_HSBtn setHidden:YES];
        }

        if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"CanAccessAccreditation"]) {

            [self.ntButton setHidden:YES];

            [_msaBtn setHidden:YES];
            [_msaSwitch setOn:NO];
            [_msaSwitch setHidden:YES];
            [_msaLbl setHidden:YES];

            [_hasGAP setHidden:YES];
            [_hasGAP setOn:NO];
            [_gapButton setHidden:YES];
            [_gapLbl setHidden:YES];

            [_hasNE setHidden:YES];
            [_hasNE setOn:NO];
            [_neButton setHidden:YES];
            [_neLbl setHidden:YES];
            //[_NFASView setHidden: FALSE];

            _signatureConstraint.constant = 10;
            //_NFASHeightConstraint.constant = 0;

            [_NVDDic setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"HasMSAQuestion"];
        }
        else {

            int height = 10;

            if (([self.NVDDic objectForKey:@"ConsignorState"] && ![[self.NVDDic objectForKey:@"ConsignorState"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] && [[self.NVDDic objectForKey:@"ConsignorState"] isEqualToString:@"NT"]) || ([self.NVDDic objectForKey:@"DestinationState"] && ![[self.NVDDic objectForKey:@"DestinationState"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] && [[self.NVDDic objectForKey:@"DestinationState"] isEqualToString:@"NT"]) || ([self.NVDDic objectForKey:@"HasNTWaybill"] && [[self.NVDDic objectForKey:@"HasNTWaybill"] boolValue])) {

                [self.ntButton setHidden:NO];

                height = height + 46;
            }
            else{
                [self.ntButton setHidden:YES];
            }

            if (![[self.NVDDic objectForKey:@"HasMSAQuestion"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] && [[self.NVDDic objectForKey:@"HasMSAQuestion"] boolValue]) {
                [_msaSwitch setOn:YES];
                [_msaBtn setHidden:NO];

                _msaConstraint.constant = height;
                height = height + 46;
            }
            else{
                [_msaSwitch setOn:NO];
                [_msaSwitch setHidden:YES];
                [_msaBtn setHidden:YES];
                [_msaLbl setHidden:YES];
            }

            if (![[self.NVDDic objectForKey:@"IsGAPAccredited"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] && [[self.NVDDic objectForKey:@"IsGAPAccredited"] boolValue]) {
                [self.hasGAP setOn:YES];
                [self.gapButton setHidden:NO];

                _gapConstraint.constant = height;
                height = height + 46;
            }
            else{
                [_hasGAP setOn:NO];
                [_hasGAP setHidden:YES];
                [_gapButton setHidden:YES];
                [_gapLbl setHidden:YES];
            }

            if (![[self.NVDDic objectForKey:@"IsNEAccredited"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] && [[self.NVDDic objectForKey:@"IsNEAccredited"] boolValue]) {
                [_hasNE setOn:YES];
                [_neButton setHidden:NO];

                _neConstraint.constant = height;
                height = height + 46;
            }
            else{
                [_hasNE setOn:NO];
                [_hasNE setHidden:YES];
                [_neButton setHidden:YES];
                [_neLbl setHidden:YES];
            }
            _signatureConstraint.constant = height;
        }

        if (![[self.NVDDic objectForKey:@"HasESC"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] && [[self.NVDDic objectForKey:@"HasESC"] boolValue]) {
            [_hasESC setOn:YES];
        }
        else{
            [_hasESC setOn:NO];
        }

        if (![[self.NVDDic objectForKey:@"HasTPA"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] && [[self.NVDDic objectForKey:@"HasTPA"] boolValue]) {
            [_hasTPA setOn:YES];
        }
        else{
            [_hasTPA setOn:NO];
        }

        if ([self.answersDic allKeys].count > 0) {
            [self loadQuestionaires];
        }

        if (_operationType != OperationType_Edit) {

            [_hasGAP setOn:NO];
            [self showGAP:_hasGAP];

            [_hasNE setOn:NO];
            [self showNE:_hasNE];
        }

        if (self.arrNFASSummary != nil){
            for (int i = 0; i < [self.arrNFASSummary count];i++){
                NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[self.arrNFASSummary objectAtIndex:i]];
                if ([dict valueForKey:@"Dentition"] != nil)
                    [dict setValue:@"" forKey:@"Dentition"];
                if ([dict valueForKey:@"FeedDays"] != nil)
                    [dict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0] forKey:@"FeedDays"];
            }
        }

        NSString *statementQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM CattleHealthStatementDetail WHERE NVDId = '%@'",[self.NVDDic objectForKey:@"NVDId"]];
        NSDictionary *dictHS = [[DBHelper getSharedInstance] getDetailsBySQL:statementQuery];
        if (dictHS != nil){
            [_NVDDic setObject:dictHS forKey:@"HSAnswers"];
        }
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"%@", exception.reason);
        }
        }
```

I think there is something wrong with UI code.**This is the code for calling the view when the segment is clicked I think I have to make change here**.

```
else if ([sender isEqual:_ans6Segment]) {

        if (_ans6Segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {

            _ans6Text1.text = @"";
            _Ans6Text1new1.text=@"";
            _ans6Text2.text = @"";
          _Ans6Text2new1.text=@"";
            _ans6Text3.text = @"";
            _Ans6Text3new1.text=@"";
            _ans6Text4.text = @"";
            _Ans6Text4new1.text=@"";
            _ans6Constraint.constant = 5;
        }
        else {

            _ans6Constraint.constant = 340;

            [self.tableView bringSubviewToFront: _addChemical];
            NSLayoutConstraint *top = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_addChemical attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:100];
            [self.view addConstraints:@[ top]];
        }
    }
```

Also there is a big white space coming in the view I don't know where is it coming from is it related to this issue I have tried decrease the Y axis and width to remove that white space but nothing worked you can see that in 
[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UXSs.jpg)
I am posting the screenshot of my Layout.

[This is the Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6ABT.png)

I know that there is something wrong with the layout that is my the UIView class. Because the id of the  text field is accessible in other textfield in different Layout.

Answer (score 0):

In many case any view is over the textfield and buttons... thats why you look like click on button but actually you clicked on front view(Which is add unfortunately in front).

Please confirm your touch event code with following code

```
[AddButton addTarget:self action:@selector(RemoveChemical1Tapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

also check with this code

```
[storeCatalog addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:storeCatalog action:@selector(onTouch:)]];
```

I hope this will work for you...

Answer (score 0):

iOS by default will fire `UITextViewTextDidBeginEditingNotification` notification when you touch a `UITextView`. By setting an observer for that notification, you will be able to handle the touch on your `UITextView`.

Register for `UITextViewTextDidBeginEditingNotification`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleTextBeginEditing:) name:UITextViewTextDidBeginEditingNotification object:textView];
```

And your handler:

```
-(void)handleTextBeginEditing:(UITextView *)sender {
    if ([sender isEqual:textView]) {
        NSLog(@"TextView tapped");
    }
}
```

For the button, I see no problem of catching the touch event using `addTarget` function. Try to check `_RemoveChemical1` at the time you call `addTarget` on it.

Comment: The UI scroll view is not letting me to handle any touch event will this code work for me?

Comment: - (void)addChemicalTapped:(UIButton *)sender {
 
    _ans6Constraint.constant = 750;
//    [self.addChemical addTarget:self action:@selector(fixDelaysContentTouches:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleTextBeginEditing:) name:UITextViewTextDidBeginEditingNotification object:_Ans6Text1new1];
    [self reloadTable];
    
}

Comment: -(void)handleTextBeginEditing:(UITextView *)sender {
    if ([sender isEqual:_Ans6Text1new1]) {
        NSLog(@"TextView tapped");
    }
}

Comment: the handleTextBeginEditing is not getting hit in debugger aswell

Comment: Does the `addChemicalTapped:` get hit by the debugger?

Comment: yes addChemicalTapped: get hit by the debugger but handleTextBeginEditing is not getting hit

Comment: I have used delaysContentTouches: aswell to delay the touch of UI scroll view still no Luck

Comment: I just realized that you're using `UITextField` instead of `UITextView`. So you may want to replace `UITextViewTextDidBeginEditingNotification ` by `UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification` & modify the handler function as well.

Comment: - (void)addChemicalTapped:(UIButton *)sender {
 
    _ans6Constraint.constant = 750;
//    [self.addChemical addTarget:self action:@selector(fixDelaysContentTouches:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleTextBeginEditing:) name:UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification object:_Ans6Text1new1];
    
    [self reloadTable];
    
}

Comment: -(void)handleTextBeginEditing:(UITextView *)sender {
    if ([sender isEqual:_Ans6Text1new1]) {
        NSLog(@"TextView tapped");
    }
    
}

Comment: Let carefully look at your `handleTextBeginEditing` function, you're still left the `sender` as `UITextView`.

Comment: I have changed it to UITextField as you can see -(void)handleTextBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender {

Comment: well, it couldn't be the problem of `UIScrollView`, might be a mistake somewhere in your code.

Comment: I tried the touch event for the _RemoveChemical1 aswell using the addTarget function that also is not working

Comment: I know that there is something wrong with the layout that is my the UIView class. Because the id of the  text field is accessible in other textfield in different Layout. So I need to make change in UIView I guess.